# How to prove that the first quadrant of the plane is closed.

Tags: general-topology

How can I prove, in topology, that:

$$X = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2;y<0;x\in\mathbb{R}\}\cup\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2;x<0,y\geq0\}$$
is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

I tried doing by its complement, but how can I prove that
$$Y= \mathbb{R}^2\setminus X=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2;x,y\geq0\}$$
is closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

I tried to use, as well, this statement:

$Y$ is closed if and only if for each $y\in \mathbb{R}^2\setminus Y$ there is a neighbourhood $N$ of $y$ such that $N\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2\setminus Y$.

Comment: If you want to use the statement, then you intend to prove that $X$  is open. If $(x, y)$ is in the first term $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2;y<0;x\in\mathbb{R}\}$, just take a disc of radius $-y/2$ around it. For the other term you will need to consider the value of $x$..

Comment: I still haven't been able to visualize your point. Can you explain it in another way? Sorry, I really didn't understand, @AndreasCaranti.

Comment: Just draw a picture, and you will see what I mean. I do not mean to be secretive, it is just that, as a teacher, I know how important it is for one to find a solution oneself, as opposed to just being told what the solution is.

Comment: Okay. No problem, I respect your position and thank you for your help and patience, @AndreasCaranti.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti I got it. My doubt was about taking the disc as being open, because in my definition, the basics are rectangles. But the idea is similar, I just need to take the coordinates of my open strategically to be a neighborhood of (x, y). Thanks! Not really giving me any more tips was essential! You are a good teacher. I appreciate it!

Comment: <blush>Thanks a lot!</blush>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $X=(\mathbb R\times\mathbb R^-)\cup(\mathbb R^-\times\mathbb R)$, you have that $X$ is the union of two obviously open sets.